# Calling static C# function from LotusScript

Tags: c#, lotusscript

I have made a C# library project containing only a static class with a static function:

```
namespace MyApp.MyTestLib
{
    public static class MyTestLib
    {
        public static string Test(string input) {
            return input.ToLower();
        }
    }
}
```

I have then compiled it and got a `MyTestLib.dll`, which I have put into the `notes/data` directory on the server.

Then I made a Notes agent:

```
Option Public
Option Declare
Use "URLDecode"

Declare Function MyTest Lib "MyTestLib.dll" Alias "Test" (ByVal JsonData As String) As String
Sub Initialize
    Print MyTest("abcd")
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

The notes agent now throws the error `External function not found`, and I am not entirely sure why that would be. It seems to have found the DLL, though - if I remove the DLL from the `data` directory, the error message is different (something like "Error loading library").

Why is that and how to fix it?

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21230705

You are trying to create Com callable wrapper, so these steps are important

Comment: @MrinalKamboj The docs tell me **Otherwise, the DLL will be created as a private assembly and you will only be able to create the object if the DLL is in the same directory as the calling program.** which is exactly what I want to do. I don't want to register it in GAC, but use it privately from the notes directory - there are many DLLs in the notes data directory, plus the DLL seems to have been found, but I cannot access the static function that's inside the DLL. The docs only tell me how to create an instance and access the instance's function.